# Click parent button from child span class (Watir/Ruby)

Tags: ruby, watir

```
<button class="class1">
  <span class="class2">Text</span> 
</button>
```

I have several instances of buttons like this on a page. I want to click the button with `class1` after finding a `span` with `class2`. When the button is clicked, `class2` changes to `class3`. Then I want to loop this until all the `class2` changes to `class3`.

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
while browser.span(:class => "class2").present? == true
  media = browser.spans(:class => "class2")
  media.each { |val|
    val.parent.button(:class => "class1").click
    sleep(1)
  }
end
```

The struggle is with `val.parent.click`. I know I shouldn't be using sleep, but this is just for testing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The line `val.parent.button(:class => "class1").click` will look for a button element within the span's parent element. Given the HTML structure, you just need to go to the parent element - ie `value.parent.click`.

I think you can do:

```
media = browser.spans(:class => "class2")
media.each { |val|
  val.parent.click
  val.wait_until { |e| e.class_name == "class3" }
}
```

Note that I've omitted the outer `while` loop. Unless spans are being switched back to "class2", I don't think it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: use `do..end` for multiline blocks? :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit, maybe? If I do a one-liner, `media.each { |val| val.tap { |v| v.parent.click }.wait_until { |e| e.class_name == "class3" } }` I can keep the braces, right? :)

Comment: Yes. What I said according to the Ruby style guide Rubocop. :)